# Write a pandas DataFrame mixing integers and floats in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, casting

I'm working with pandas DataFrames full of float numbers, but with integers in one every three lines (the whole line is made of integers). When I make a `print df`, all the values displayed are shown as floats (the integers values have a ``.000000```added) for example :

```
                aromatics      charged        polar      unpolar
Ac_obs_counts  712.000000  1486.000000  2688.000000  2792.000000
Ac_obs_freqs     0.092732     0.193540     0.350091     0.363636
Ac_pvalues       0.524752     0.099010     0.356436     0.495050
Am_obs_counts   10.000000    59.000000    62.000000    50.000000
Am_obs_freqs     0.055249     0.325967     0.342541     0.276243
Am_pvalues       0.495050     0.980198     0.356436     0.009901
Ap_obs_counts   18.000000    34.000000    83.000000    78.000000
Ap_obs_freqs     0.084507     0.159624     0.389671     0.366197
Ap_pvalues       0.524752     0.039604     0.980198     0.663366
```

When I use `df.iloc[range(0, len(df.index), 3)]`, I see integers displayed :

```
               aromatics  charged  polar  unpolar
Ac_obs_counts        712     1486   2688     2792
Am_obs_counts         10       59     62       50
Ap_obs_counts         18       34     83       78
Pa_obs_counts         47       81    125      144
Pf_obs_counts         31       58     99      109
Pg_obs_counts         27      106    102      108
Ph_obs_counts          7       49     42       36
Pp_obs_counts         15       83     45       65
Ps_obs_counts         57      125    170      216
Pu_obs_counts         14       62    102       84
```

When I use `df.to_csv("mydf.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8")` , the integers are written as floats ; how can I force the writing as integers for these lines ? Would it be better to split the data in two DataFrames ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about writing integer values as float in the csv file? It usually don't matter too much if your integers are written as float. One way to can do is to convert everything into string and then save as csv.

Comment: Yes, it's not a big issue actually, but these numbers represent countings, which, by convenience, are usually integers ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `object`

```
df.astype('object')
Out[1517]: 
              aromatics   charged     polar   unpolar
Ac_obs_counts       712      1486      2688      2792
Ac_obs_freqs   0.092732   0.19354  0.350091  0.363636
Ac_pvalues     0.524752   0.09901  0.356436   0.49505
Am_obs_counts        10        59        62        50
Am_obs_freqs   0.055249  0.325967  0.342541  0.276243
Am_pvalues      0.49505  0.980198  0.356436  0.009901
Ap_obs_counts        18        34        83        78
Ap_obs_freqs   0.084507  0.159624  0.389671  0.366197
Ap_pvalues     0.524752  0.039604  0.980198  0.663366
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but only for displaying the frame on the screen (that's a good start ^^), but it doesn't when i use df.to_csv :/

Comment: @Micawber that is csv display problem , You can try to open your csv as txt, right click open as txt

Comment: It doesn't change anything, but I guess it's not a big deal afterall ^^. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Micawber IDK, whether it help, if so can you consider upvote and accept ?